I have a lot of "texture glitchs" from afar, how to get ride of that?
I'm sorry about that unprecise title but I don't really know how to describe this :
When I'm close to objects, they appear with the right texture, but afar there is tons of "holes" in it, and that appear in the render too...
That happens very often with hairs and cloths but also with some fournitures and walls...
I'm posting 2 screenshots because it's not easy to describe :
The second is very close, so there is no problem, and on the first you can see the "holes" in the hairs texture.
I tried to change "backface culling", "blend mode" and shadow mode" in material properties settings but nothing works
This problem also appears when I'm in "display in solid mode", so i's probably not a texture bug but I don't know what it can be...
Thank you



It's hard to tell without sample file. If you're using cycles you may want to increase number of transparency bounces https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/render_settings/light_paths.html#max-bounces
This may be required if you have a lot of semitrasparent overlapping parts.

It can be a mesh "z-fighting" with the mesh underneath it, or, indeed, a transparency issue. Please upload your .blend file.

Or a much too high clip end value.

I'd also suspect a too big clipping zone. The default start/end is 0.1 to 1 000, yours is 0.1 to 10 000, so essentially 10x bigger.

Thank you all for your fast answers in comments !
You were right, that was caused by a too small clip start value. It was 0.01, I changed it for 0.1 or 1 mm according to the scene scale. The clip end value doesn't seem to affect that problem.
